# What will come after a US withdrawal from Afghanistan?

Tags: nato, afghanistan, taliban

The United States and the Taliban may be nearing an agreement to withdraw U.S. troops from Afghanistan after more than 17 years of conflict.

In return, the Taliban would commit to refusing access to anti-American organizations such as al-Qaida on its territory.

but as an Afghan Citizen i am worried for the future of afghanistan and the future of men and women. would the taliban take over afghanistan and be just like old time when they were running the goverment. women wont be allowed to study, no music, men must have beard and allot more.
we have achived so much in this 17 years and we have lost brave afghan and other allies fighting aginst terror, all that now for noting

Comment: I understand that you might be uncertain about what an US withdrawal would mean for your country, but we generally don't answer questions which ask us to predict the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different opinions on this problem from different sides of the conflict and a lot of unknown facts. On one hand,Taliban made promises where for example the rights of women will be kept intact in the case of United States withdrawal from Afghanistan. It is unknown whether this will be true or not. For now, the Taliban haven't even managed to cease fighting after negotiation with the United States. Most public groups in Afghanistan and abroad doesn't believe this will be the case and are worried Taliban will restore fundamentalist governance after the United States withdrawal from Afghanistan.

The Strength of Taliban is also an element you need to think about. The stronger Taliban will be, more likely it's going to have the power to govern in any way it wants.

Another unknown is whether the United States will actually leave Afghanistan completely or not. The actions of Donald Trump's policy on this topic aren't very clear. There are also presidential elections coming to the United States, where a possible change of presidency could completely change the situation of troops withdrawal from Afghanistan.

Comment: so what happens for example Americans withdraw completly and after some time the taliban break their promise and restore fundamelaist goverment, what will the west will do in this case?

Comment: I think, that the West will deeply regret about it in speeches on different international forums. Really, two world superpowers have entered Afganistan at some time in the past, and both have/are withdrawing.

Comment: @Navid2132 We don't know. Countries generally only interfere in the internal affairs of other countries if they have an interest in that affair. So whether or not "The West" would interfere if the Taliban start to abuse the Afghan population would depend on the geopolitical situation at that time and if they would see any possible gain from that.

Comment: @Navid2132 That's very hard to say. It can depend on who will be the president of the United States. Other countries from the Middle East could also have some impact on the country. I wouldn't personally hope some other country will come and fight the Taliban once the United States withdraws from Afghanistan.

Comment: i know its very to sad to see everthing will go back to same after all the sacrifises